# how to combine two data source into one?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have records in two tables, and 1 object,
i want to retrieve data from both tables into 1 gridview, (both tables have same fields) i can not have joins because i need to show all rows

here is my code:

```
var query = from all in DB.Movies
            where all.IsActive
            select new MoviesObject
            {
                PhotoId = all.PhotoId,
                Title = all.Title,
                Description = all.ShortDescription
            };
var querytwo = from all in DB.movieslisttwo
               where all.IsActive
               select new MoviesObject
               {
                   PhotoId = all.PhotoId,
                   Title = all.Title,
                   Description = all.ShortDescription
               ;
return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return query.Concat(query2).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can call `.Union()` to skip duplicates.

Comment: Caution, Union might not work as you expect if MoviesObject doesn't implement Equals to compare the PhotoId since each list will contain different instances of any duplicates

Comment: @TrevorPilley: No; I assume that he's not using LINQ to Objects.